# Atomicity of writev() system call in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I've looked in the kernel source for linux kernel 4.4.0-57-generic and don't see any locks in the `writev()` source.  Is there something I'm missing?  I don't see how `writev()` is atomic or thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Not a kernel expert here, but I'll share my point of view anyway. Feel free to spot any mistakes.

Browsing the kernel (v4.9 though I wouldn't expect it to be so different), and trying to trace the `writev(2)` system call, I can observe subsequent function calls that create the following path:

1. [`SYSCALL_DEFINE3(writev, ..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L1014)
2. [`do_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L936)
3. [`vfs_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L903)
4. [`do_readv_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L837)

Now the path branches, depending on whether a `write_iter` method is implemented and hooked on the `struct file_operations` field of the `struct file` that the system call is referring to.

- If it's not `NULL`, the path is:

5a. [`do_iter_readv_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L677), which calls the method `filp->f_op->write_iter(..)` [at this point](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L695).

- If it is `NULL`, the path is:

5b. [`do_loop_readv_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L702), which calls repeatedly in a loop the method `filp->f_op->write` [at this point](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.9#L714).

---

So, as far as I understand, the `writev()` system call is as thread safe as the underlying `write()` (or `write_iter()`) is, which of course can be implemented in various ways, e.g. in a device driver, and may or may not use locks according to its needs and its design.

---

**EDIT**:

In kernel v4.4 the paths look pretty similar:

1. [`SYSCALL_DEFINE3(writev, ..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.4#L872)
2. [`vfs_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.4#L839)
3. [`do_readv_writev(..)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=4.4#L774)

and then it depends on whether the `write_iter` method as a field in `struct file_operations` of the `struct file` is `NULL` or not, just like the case in v4.9, described above.

Comment: Or anyone else anyway? I'm in the process of learning this stuff, and spotting any mistake would be helpful.

Comment: That's the same path I saw.  It seemed strange to then depend on the write method below `filp->f_op->write` for atomicity after I read this writev(2):   ***The data transfers performed by readv() and writev() are atomic:** the data written by writev() is written as a single block that is not intermingled with output from writes in other processes (but see pipe(7) for an exception); analogously, readv() is guaranteed to read a contiguous block of data from the file, regardless of read operations performed in other threads or processes that have file descriptors . . .

Comment: @C6Up1bQ73STi29cA I see your point. I believe it's obvious how atomicity can be achieved when relying upon `do_iter_readv_writev()` and method `write_iter`, as the latter can acquire properly the necessary lock to perform the data transfer atomically. However, in the case where `write_iter` isn't implemented at all, and thus `writev(2)` essentially relies upon the `write` method called repeatedly by hand, in a loop, I honestly don't know how it can be atomic. My best guess would be that in cases like this, the `write_iter` method **must** be implemented to achieve atomicity. ...

Comment: @C6Up1bQ73STi29cA ... Maybe even an implementation of the simple `write` method is then pointless and omitted, as in the case of [ext4](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/file.c?v=4.4#L696) that @Tsyvarev mentioned.

Comment: Thanks chrk and Tsyvarev.  It's possible that drivers **must** implement an atomic write() method, as @Tsyvarev pointed out for ext4. I'd be more comforted if I saw the lock in writev().  I'm writing to a socket, so I'll pull open that code's write() method.  With a preemptive kernel, no lock, no atomic.  Of course, there may be kernel magic which will not preempt writev().  I probably should have posted in Unix & Linux; I think I will.  Thank s again.

Answer (score 1):

VFS (Virtual File System) **by itself doesn't garantee** *atomicity* of `writev()` call. It just calls filesystem-specific `.write_iter` method of `struct file_operations`.

It is **responsibility of specific filesystem implementation** for make method *atomically* write to the file.

For example, in ext4 filesystem function [ext4_file_write_iter](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/file.c?v=4.4#L92) uses

```
mutex_lock(&inode->i_mutex);
```

for make writting atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in fs.h:

```
static inline void file_start_write(struct file *file)
{
    if (!S_ISREG(file_inode(file)->i_mode))
        return;
    __sb_start_write(file_inode(file)->i_sb, SB_FREEZE_WRITE, true);
}
```

and then in super.c:

```
/*
 * This is an internal function, please use sb_start_{write,pagefault,intwrite}
 * instead.
 */
int __sb_start_write(struct super_block *sb, int level, bool wait)
{
    bool force_trylock = false;
    int ret = 1;

#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
/*
 * We want lockdep to tell us about possible deadlocks with freezing
 * but it's it bit tricky to properly instrument it. Getting a freeze
 * protection works as getting a read lock but there are subtle
 * problems. XFS for example gets freeze protection on internal level
 * twice in some cases, which is OK only because we already hold a
 * freeze protection also on higher level. Due to these cases we have
 * to use wait == F (trylock mode) which must not fail.
 */
  if (wait) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < level - 1; i++)
        if (percpu_rwsem_is_held(sb->s_writers.rw_sem + i)) {
            force_trylock = true;
            break;
        }
  }
#endif
  if (wait && !force_trylock)
    percpu_down_read(sb->s_writers.rw_sem + level-1);
  else
    ret = percpu_down_read_trylock(sb->s_writers.rw_sem + level-1);

  WARN_ON(force_trylock & !ret);
  return ret;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__sb_start_write);
```

Thanks again.